# Creating a vector from input numbers in assembly at&t

Tags: assembly, vector, x86, att

Lets say I have the next numbers given as input:
1
4
3
5
10
And I want to create a vector v that contains this numbers.
I wrote the next code:

```
.data 
    v: .space 128 # v=the space I gave for the vector
    N: .space 4 #N= the numbers from the input
    n: .space 4 #n= the number of the numbers given as input
    indexV: .space 4 
    index: .space 4
    formatScanf: .asciz "%ld"
    formatPrintf: .asciz "%ld "
.text
.global main 
main:

    pushl $n
    pushl $formatScanf
    call scanf
    popl %ebx
    popl %ebx
    
lea v, %edi
movl $0, indexV
et_vector: 
            
        movl indexV, %ecx
        cmp %ecx, n
        je et_print

        pushl $N
        pushl $formatScanf
        call scanf
        popl %ebx
        popl %ebx
        
        movl $N, (%edi, %ecx, 4)
        incl indexV

    jmp et_vector

movl $0, index
et_print:
movl index, %ecx
cmp %ecx, n
je et_exit
lea v, %edi
movl (%edi, %ecx, 4), %ebx

pushl %ebx
pushl $formatPrintf
call printf
popl %ebx
popl %ebx
pushl $0
call fflush
popl %ebx
incl index
jmp et_print



et_exit:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

It gives the next error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
I am not sure how to create the vector.
Could u tell me if it's at least somewhat correct?
Or if u have a solution that works.

I tried to allocate a space for the vector in edi then insert the numbers given as input then print the vector.

Comment: Can you be more specific: are you trying to debug this segmentation fault or if you're not sure how to create the vector, maybe you haven't finished the code as yet?

Comment: Well both, I want to correct the segmentation fault and to get some opinions on the way I approach the problem, if its somewhat correct, if its completely wrong, if any commands are wrongly used. I am new to asm and I am not rly sure of most things that I write.

Comment: If you're trying to debug a segmentation fault, then at minimum you would share the location of the fault (the faulting instruction) and the register contents at the fault.

Comment: Also, when you're debugging start with the smallest possible input, like one number, and get that working.  Then move on to input of two numbers.

Comment: Oki I will see, but the code that i wrote makes sense to you? Aside from the segmentation fault, does reading the code seems to serve the purpose of creating a vector?

Comment: Like without knowing what it should do could u have understood what is supposed to do?

Comment: Something like that should work. Likely that scanf or printf is changing a register that you're relying upon to hold a variable, i.e. you're using a call-clobbered register %ecx and after a call comes back the register has been clobbered. You should be able to see it in single step debugging (step "over" the library calls). See https://www.dyncall.org/docs/manual/manualse11.html